# how to work at the same time with multiple files inside file name array in linux shell script?

Tags: shell, filenames, sha

I have a shell script and i read all .s files in the specified folder first and then compile them to object file with a loop and after that link them to executable file.
this:

```
FILES=PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.s

for sfile in $FILES 
do

echo "------------------------------------------------"
    echo $sfile
    objectFile="${sfile%.s}.o"
    exefile="${objectFile%.o}.ex"

    simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-as -o  $objectFile $sfile

done
```

but I have a problem: in sha mibench program we have 2 files that  each of them is in this flow:

```
.c -> .s -> .o
```

but at the last stage two .o files should be linked into one executable file.

how I can get two file names at the same time and create a command to link them.

main code is this:

```
simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-ld -o __sha.ex _sha.o _sha_driver.o
```

is there any way to see inside of FILES like this:

```
OFILES=PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.o
simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-ld -o $exefile OFILES[0] OFILES[1]
```

and after that doing that in a loop for all files with this pattern
first file is like `*.o` or `*_main.o`
second is: `*_driver.o`

Thanks

Comment: How come you're not using a makefile for this?

Comment: "shell" is too generic -- not all shells support arrays. You'll need to use a specific shell with the right extension, such as bash, if you want array support.

Comment: Using upper-case variable names in shell is bad practice for things which are neither (1) environment variables, or (2) intentional references to shell built-ins. Using at least one lower-case character in each variable intended to be local to your shell instance prevents namespace conflicts, and is otherwise considered good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this file and it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
#compile to assembly:

FILES=*_driver.s

for sdriverfile in $FILES 
do

echo "------------------------------------------------"
# s file
    echo $sdriverfile
    sfile="${sdriverfile%_driver.s}.s"
    echo $sfile

# object files
    obj="${sfile%.s}.o"
    obj_driver="${sdriverfile%.s}.o"

#exe file
    exefile="${sfile%.s}_as.ex"
    echo $exefile

#compile
    /home/mahdi/programs/simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-as -o  $obj $sfile
    /home/mahdi/programs/simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-as -o  $obj_driver $sdriverfile

#link
    /home/mahdi/programs/simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-ld -o $exefile $obj $obj_driver -L /home/mahdi/programs/simplescalar/sslittle-na-sstrix/lib -lc -L /home/mahdi/programs/simplescalar/lib/gcc-lib/sslittle-na-sstrix/2.7.2.3/ -lgcc



done
```

thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is possible in shell.  However many people find that the make utility is better for building software than shell scripts simply because of these dependencies.  take a look at [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).  Its documentation contains numerous examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I agree that make is the right tool for the use case... but if someone else finds this question during a search, they're likely to have a use case where shell arrays really are the right tool (particularly as its subject line says nothing whatsoever about make, or about compilation). Having a literal answer, in addition to the best-practice-for-your-use-case answer, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: Your tags "`linux` `shell`" do not specify a specific shell. POSIX sh, the standard specifying minimum required behavior for `/bin/sh`, does not support arrays; you should use a specific shell, such as bash or ksh, which does. To do this, you need to start your script with an appropriate shebang (such as `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`), and do any manual invocations with the correct shell (so `bash -x myscript` if you would otherwise use `sh -x myscript`... though if you've set the shebang correctly and have `+x` permissions, you can always just `./myscript`)

---

```
# this is broken
FILES=PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.s
```

...does not create an array.

```
# this works in bash, ksh, and zsh
files=( PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.s )
```

*does* create an array, which can be expanded as `"${files[@]}"`. So:

```
# this works in bash and ksh, and probably zsh
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  ...
done
```

However, in this particular case, you don't have a reason to use an array at all:

```
# this works with absolutely any POSIX-compatible shell
for file in PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.s; do
  echo "$sfile"
  objectFile=${sfile%.s}.o
  exefile=${objectFile%.o}.ex

  simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-as -o "$objectFile" "$sfile"
done
```

Note a few corrections made in the above:

- The right-hand-side of assignments in with no literal whitespace in their syntax do not need to be quoted.
- All expansions (such as `$objectFile`) **do** need to be quoted, so, `"$objectFile"`.
- ...yes, this *does* include `echo`; to test this, run `s='*'` and compare the output of `echo $s` to `echo "$s"`.

---

To address the follow-up question you edited in:

```
ofiles=( PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.o )
simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-ld -o "$exefile" "${ofiles[0]}" "${ofiles[1]}"
```

...is a literal answer, but this would need to be edited if you had two or more outputs. Much better to do it this way instead:

```
ofiles=( PTscalar_1.0/mibenchforpt/security/sha/*.o )
simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-ld -o "$exefile" "${ofiles[@]}"
```

Comment: POSIX sh *does* support arrays; it has one per subshell. The usual operators are `set -- ...`, `shift`, `"$1"` (`"$2"`...), `"$@"`

Comment: @JoSo That's not "arrays", that's _an array_. (Though if you're counting argv, there's more than one-per-subshell, since each function has its own).

Comment: Yup *function* I meant, sorry for the confusion. I don't know what "counting argv" means--there is only this one type of array. And it's hard to find a situation where 1 per function is not sufficient. As long as you use shell for what it was made for, that is, connecting programs.

Comment: @JoSo It is entirely untrue that "there is only one type of array", if you're going beyond pure POSIX sh (example: ksh, bash and zsh arrays are sparse, while argv can't be). I'm not sure that arguing the point here advances anything, though. Find me as nDuff in irc.freenode.org #bash?

Comment: I think I've made it quite unambiguous that I'm talking about `sh`. Thanks for the chat invitation, I'm not interested in bash.